# data science name error: in spyder using python

Tags: python, data-science, analytics, spyder, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGHYX.png)

data science problem there is some error in my code please some one help with it. I have tried multiple times can anyone suggest what to doo

Comment: Don't attach images, post code directly into the question. In your code you never defined variable `churn` that you're trying to call hence the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have never defined a variable called `churn`.
I think you wanted to use the variable `data`, where you created the data frame.